# firebase auth with phone number

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase and I am trying to register users with phone auth.

here is my full activity code

```
class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
 private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val timeoutSeconds = 60L
    private lateinit var storedVerificationId: String
    private lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
        registerbtn.setOnClickListener { registerButtonClicked() }
        verifybtn.setOnClickListener { verifyButtonClicked() }
    }
fun registerButtonClicked() {
        registerPhoneNumber(editTextPhone.text.toString())
    }
private fun verifyButtonClicked() {
       verifyUser(editTextPhone.text.toString())
    }
private fun registerPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) {
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) 
            .setTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(activity)           
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)  
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }

private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                   }

        override fun onCodeSent(
            verificationId: String,
            token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
        ) {
            storedVerificationId = verificationId
            resendToken = token
        }
    }

private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                } 
            }
    }

fun verifyUser(verificationCode: String) {
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(storedVerificationId, verificationCode)
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
    }
```

I got an exception that `storedVerificationId` was not set, even though I set it already in `onCodeSent`
What am I doing wrong here? and is the flow that I am following correct?

Comment: We can't see here where `storedVerificationId` is declared, so it's not possible for us to know how to fix this.  The error message is coming from the Kotlin compiler, and has nothing to do with the way Firebase works.  Please edit the question to focus on the source code that deals with `storedVerificationId`.  It should contain a [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: they are defined as lateint var in the class and I set them in onCodeSent. updated the question. @DougStevenson

Comment: I don't see any lateinit vars at all.  Please edit the question to show the [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Don't just describe it - copy the code into your question so we can see what the compiler sees.

Comment: sorry about that. I just updated the question and posted the whole activity @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kotlin runtime is giving you this message because it saw that that `storedVerificationId` was not given a non-null value before it's used in `verifyUser`.

You will likely just want to remove the `lateinit` keyword from it, and allow a null initial value.  You will have to check for null to ensure it's set before you use it.

```
    private var storedVerificationId: String? = null


    fun verifyUser(verificationCode: String) {
        if (storedVerificationId != null) {
            val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(storedVerificationId, verificationCode)
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }
        else {
            // decide what you want to do if it hasn't been given a value yet.
        }
    }
```